# Differences in issue numbers between SONAR dashboard and its REST API

Tags: sonarqube

I'm writing a regular SONAR mail report as suggested in different posts and while playing around found a difference in number between the issues shown in the regular SONAR dashboard and the number produced by the REST API, e.g.

```
.../sonar/api/issues/search?severities=CRITICAL&componentRoots=HEAD:diverse
```

It does not occur on every query and seems so be more often at large numbers. The REST API number is also always larger than the one from the dashboard.

(1) Has anybody experienced similar results or are there known bugs (couldn't find any on google or the mailing lists)?

(2) If there is a hidden command to bypass the 10.000 issue max cap, I'd also appreciate that. :-)

SONARQUBE version is 3.6.2.

Greetings and thanks,
LastFreeNickname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) If one adds

```
&resolved=false
```

to the query, the numbers get equal.

(2) It seems that there is no way to avoid the cap. Nevertheless the /timemachine does not have this cap but provides the whole numbers.

```
.../sonar/api/timemachine?resource=HEAD:diverse&metrics=major_violations&fromDateTime=2013-12-05T00:00:00+0100
```